# Fetch the check/unchecked "checkbox" in php

Tags: php, html, algorithm

I have written the following pieces of code to edit or update my permission so that when I click the edit button, the check/uncheck boxes should appear.

```
<?php
}
}
$id=$_REQUEST['user'];
if(isset($_GET['showtab']) && $_GET['showtab']==1) {
$result=doQuery("SELECT user,
                        account,
                        firstname,
                        lastname,
                        branchname,
                        username 
                        FROM web_webusers WHERE user='".(int)$id."'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $user=$test['user'];
            $firstname=$test['firstname'];
            $lastname=$test['lastname'];
            $branchname=$test['branchname'];
            $username=$test['username'];

$result=doQuery("SELECT user,
                        AllowAddAddressBook,
                        AllowEditAddressBook,
                        AllowAddPrealert,
                        AllowEditPrealert,
                        AllowAddUser 
                        FROM web_clientuser_permission WHERE user='".       (int)$id."'");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $user=$test['user'];
            $AllowAddAddressBook=$test['AllowAddAddressBook'];
            $AllowEditAddressBook=$test['AllowEditAddressBook'];
            $AllowAddPrealert=$test['AllowAddPrealert'];
            $AllowEditPrealert=$test['AllowEditPrealert'];
            $AllowAddUser=$test['AllowAddUser'];
}

?>
<div class="row">
```

>
     > Allow Add Address Book

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <input type="hidden" name="AllowEditAddressBook" id="AllowEditAddressBook" value="0"<?php echo ($AllowEditAddressBook==1) ?  ' check' : '' ?>>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="AllowEditAddressBook" id="AllowEditAddressBook" value="1">&nbsp;Allow Edit Address Book</label>
```

>
     > Allow add Pre-alert

>
     > Allow Edit Pre-alert

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="hidden" name="AllowAddUser" id="AllowAddUser" value="0" <?php echo ($AllowAddUser==1) ?  ' check' : '' ?>>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="AllowAddUser" id="AllowAddUser" value="1" <?php echo ($AllowAddUser==1) ?  ' check' : '' ?>>&nbsp;Allow Add User</label>
</div>
</div>
<br>


<center>
<button type="submit" name="saveuserinfo" value="1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
<center></div>
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am asking for? Any inputs on how to achieve the concept that I am asking for will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorials here for broader and clearer explanation
https://www.formget.com/php-checkbox/